# Alpha zero to UIView but Alpha 1 to children controls

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, opacity

I'm having a hard time making my controls inside an UIView visible while the UIView is invisible.

I searched and I was told I have to change the hierarchy of controls in order to do that, I refuse to believe it is that ugly.

Does anyone have any idea how to deal with it?

By the way, I want the controls inside a UIView because I will make if drag with Gerture Recognizer

Comment: actuly not getting your Point can u tel me in brief please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the background color property of the UIView you want to be invisible to `[UIColor clearColor]`

Comment: Your answer made me realize to change the UIView color do "Default" on the Storyboard, and it worked fine, thanks